# Besides the eleven, who are the other possible wives of Muhammad?

Tags: wives-of-the-prophet

It seems Prophet Muhammad definitely had eleven wives, and possibly more.  These eleven women are:  1. [Khadijah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khadija_bint_Khuwaylid), 2. [Sawda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawda_bint_Zam%CA%BFa), 3. [Aisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aisha), 4. [Hafsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafsa_bint_Umar), 5. [Zaynab bint Khuzayma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaynab_bint_Khuzayma), 6. [Umm Salama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umm_Salama), 7. [Zaynab bint Jahsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaynab_bint_Jahsh), 8. [Juwayriyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juwayriyya_bint_al-Harith), 9. [Ramlah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramla_bint_Abi_Sufyan), 10. [Safiyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safiyya_bint_Huyayy), 11. [Maymunah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maymunah_bint_al-Harith).  These seem established, and this matches [an Islam Q&A fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/47072).

However, the Wikipedia page previously ([18 January 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Muhammad%27s_wives&oldid=760641949)) said: "...the thirteen women..."  And the Islam-critical site [WikiIslam](http://wikiislam.net/wiki/List_of_Muhammads_Wives_and_Concubines) writes: "...a total of fifteen women, though only ever eleven at one time.." (citing The History of al-Tabari (vol. IX) The Last Years of the Prophet: The Formation of the State.)

**Question**: Besides these eleven, who are the other possible wives of Muhammad?

Doing some searching, others possible wives include 12. [Maria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_al-Qibtiyya) (listed [here](http://islamawareness.net/Muhammed/ibn_kathir_wives.html)) and 13. Rayhaanah bint ‘Amr al-Nadariyyah (mentioned in the [Islam Q&A fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/47072)), which I think is the same person as [Rayhana bint Zayd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayhana_bint_Zayd) on Wikipedia.  There may be more I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 11 women you have quoted are those who are called mothers of believers,as Muhammad () has married them and consummated marriage (also read [islamqa #13344](https://islamqa.info/en/13344)). And yes Rayhana bint Zayd ibn 'Amr (or bint sham'on -Simon- ibn Zayd) al-Nadariyyah (in her case [ibn Sa'ad ابن سعد](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Sa%27d) reported two contradicting narrations, one saying she became a concubine and one a wife, she died before the death of our Prophet) and Maria al-Qibtiya (the Coptic) is among those who are discussed among scholars (concubine or wife?).

[This Arabic fatwa #24581](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/24581) on islamweb says those women are the well known women he () was married with, but about the women he might have proposed to but didn't marry or married and divorced before consummation or whom might have offered themselves for marriage and were "rejected" is discussed most scholars say they were 4 or 5 but some said 30 (I've encountered something like this in a shi'a source).

But people of knowledge about his biography don't know it and reject this high number, what they know about is that he asked for the hand of al-Jawniyah and when she saw, him she said: "I seek refuge with Allah from you". He () said: “You are protected from me.” and didn't marry her. And al-Kalbiya الكلبية, and the woman on whom's waist he saw something white and the one whom offered herself for marriage but he married her a sahabi with some suwar of the Quran as a mahr. Imam al-Qurtobi quoted a hadith of 'Aishah expressing her jealousy of those women who came and offered them selves for marriage as I quoted here: [Under what conditions is it acceptable for a Muslim woman to express a desire to marry a specific man?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/under-what-conditions-is-it-acceptable-for-a-muslim-woman-to-express-a-desire-to). So it is possible that there were more, but a marriage didn't happen as it seems.

This is related to my question [Whom did the Prophet divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35360/whom-did-the-prophet-divorce)